# BB10 Formcontrol Submit can't be stopped

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I'm using a form in a phonegap app for bb10. I'd like to keep the form so the on-screen keyboard 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons can be used. However, there is no way to suppress the form from submitting to the 'action' when the on-screen keyboard submit button is used. It also appears to always use method='get', which isn't ideal. A normal  works as expected when I 'return false;' onSubmit - only the on-screen keyboard Submit button can't be stopped. I'm using the Simulator browser to test, but the behaviour is the same on device.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function submitHandler()
{
    return false;
}
-->
</script>
<form onSubmit="submitHandler();" action="">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="test1" name="test1" class="input-field" id="test1">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="test2" name="test2" class="input-field" id="test2">
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return false;"/>
</form>
```

I'd rather do validation and submission in other parts of my code - although it seems to always. Is there a way to suppress the form from submitting when using the OSK submit button?